# Probability Multiplication involving "and"

Tags: probability

While I was solving multiplcation of probability problem, I came to the conclusion that I could not undertsand.

$P(A\cap B | C) = \frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)} = P(A|C) * P(B|A) = \frac{P(A\cap C)}{P(C)}*\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}$.

But I could not really understnad how $\frac{P(A\cap C)}{P(C)}*\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}$ works. How did $P(A)$ in the denominator cancelled out to make $P(A\cap B\cap C)$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It **doesn't** usually work.  Generally: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid C)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)}{\mathsf P(C)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap C)}{\mathsf P(C)}\cdot\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)}{\mathsf P(A\cap C)}\\[2ex]&=\mathsf P(A\mid C)\,\mathsf P(B\mid A\cap C)\end{align}$$

---

The *special* cases where $\mathsf P(B\mid A\cap C)=\mathsf P(B\mid A)$, are those where $B$ and $C$ are *conditionally* independent for given $A$.  If and only if *that* does:$$\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid C)=\mathsf P(A\mid C)\,\mathsf P(B\mid A)$$